# try to make recursion php

Tags: php, recursion, binary-search-tree

i try to make balanced tree with php but i always got error like

```
BinarySearchTree Object ( 
    [_root:BinarySearchTree:private] => BinarySearchNode Object ( 
        [val] => 8 
        [left] => 
        [right] => BinarySearchTree Object *RECURSION* ) )
```

my code is

```
public function buildTreeUtil($nodes,$start,$end)
{
    if ($start > $end)
        return NULL;

    $mid = ($start + $end)/2;

    $this->_root = new BinarySearchNode($nodes[$mid]);
    $this->_root->left  = $this->buildTreeUtil($nodes, $start, $mid-1);
    $this->_root->right = $this->buildTreeUtil($nodes, $mid+1, $end);

    return $this;
}
```

i call my function like `$this->buildTreeUtil([5,6,7,8,10],0,4)` please help me :(

Comment: You need to round `$mid` to an integer.

Comment: i still got recursion..
7
5
(5 -> right)6   8 (8 -> right) 10
i want to make tree like that